# Cordova/Phonegap Error (ChildBrowser)

Tags: javascript, cordova, childbrowser

I was debugging my Phonegap application and I got an error in my js.

You can see the error [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGLjF.png).

I don't know why it's being executed as undefined

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is the 'ChildBrowser' declared in your file? Or have you included/lined ChildBrowser.js file in your index.html?

Comment: Yes it is @geeniewanted